# Adding a new child view to my main view using addContentView

Tags: android, android-view

I was following a tutorial and was adding a new view like this:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_potential);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_potential);
    layout.addView(textView);
```

But using setContentView caused issues when I wanted to remove a view and go back to the main view.

So I tried using addContentView like this:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addContentView(R.layout.activity_display_potential);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_potential);
    layout.addView(textView);
```

I thought it was just be a simple change, but I am getting this message:

> addContentView cannot be applied to int.

Is addContentView the wrong approach to adding a child view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the declaration of the method :

`addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`

You can see that it's not the same as `setContentView`. That one just takes the `id` of a view to set, e.g. an `int`. This one you need to provide the actual view, which you can get using `findViewById` or some other way, and the layout params.

> Very useful thing I learned: Hit `CTRL+P` (or `CMD+P` on mac) when you're inside of the brackets of any method and you'll get the parameter list. It will help you see the exact parameter type and order you need to provide for that method.